# How to get new Access Token in Box api after it getting expire

Tags: ios, access-token, box

Below is the procedure given in Box Api tutorial to get new Access Token.

curl  https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token

-d 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token={valid refresh token}&client_id=     {your_client_id}&client_secret={your_client_secret}'

-X POST

This is my code

```
 NSString* refresh =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%@}",[[arrUseraccounts objectAtIndex:[BoxDownloadFileViewControlller getSharedInstance].index] objectForKey:@"refresh_token"]];

    NSString* clientId =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%@}",[BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.clientID];
    NSString* clientSecret =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%@}", [BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.clientSecret];

   // NSDictionary * dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:refresh forKey:@"refresh_token"];

    ASIFormDataRequest *postParams = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token?"]];
    //
    //    ASIFormDataRequest *postParams = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@",refresh,clientId,clientSecret]]];

        [postParams setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    //[postParams setPostBody:data];
    [postParams setPostValue:@"refresh_token" forKey:@"grant_type"];
    [postParams setPostValue:refresh forKey:@"refresh_token"];
    [postParams setPostValue:clientId forKey:@"client_id"];
    [postParams setPostValue:clientSecret forKey:@"client_secret"];

    [postParams startAsynchronous];
    postParams.delegate = self ;
    postParams.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"accessToken" forKey:@"id"];

    NSLog(@"Url is ---> %@",postParams.url);
    NSLog(@"response string is-----> %@",postParams.responseString);
```

I'm getting the following issue .

```
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client credentials are invalid"}
```

Please suggest mne how to pass the parameters given in Box Api tutorial .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution .

```
NSString* refresh =your refresh token;

NSString* clientId =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.clientID];
NSString* clientSecret =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [BoxSDK sharedSDK].OAuth2Session.clientSecret];

ASIFormDataRequest *postParams = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token?"]];

[postParams setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[postParams setPostValue:@"refresh_token" forKey:@"grant_type"];
[postParams setPostValue:refresh forKey:@"refresh_token"];
[postParams setPostValue:clientId forKey:@"client_id"];
[postParams setPostValue:clientSecret forKey:@"client_secret"];

[postParams startAsynchronous];
postParams.delegate = self ;
postParams.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"accessToken" forKey:@"id"];

NSLog(@"Url is ---> %@",postParams.url);
```